# iOS Widget Extension: "Failed to show Widget" on running with widget extension scheme

Tags: ios, widgetkit

I recently encountered a problem while developing an iOS app with a widget extension.

In the beginning, I added a widget extension to the newly created project using the template code provided by Xcode without any changes. It turned out that the widget worked as expected after running with the auto-generated scheme for the extension.

After adding some code to the app and the extension, it seems that there are some problems with the widget extension. I haven’t even noticed that there might be something wrong with the widget extension until I found the widget missing from the widget gallery. After noticing the problem, I tried to run the project using the widget’s scheme. But it showed me the following error message:

```
SendProcessControlEvent:toPid: encountered an error: Error 
Domain=com.apple.dt.deviceprocesscontrolserviceCode=8 "Failed 
to show Widget '**' error: Error 
Domain=SBAvocadoDebuggingControllerErrorDomain Code=1 "Failed 
to get descriptors for extensionBundleID (**)" 
UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to get descriptors for 
extensionBundleID (**)}." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=
Failed to show Widget '**' error: Error 
Domain=SBAvocadoDebuggingControllerErrorDomain Code=1 "Failed 
to get descriptors for extensionBundleID (**)" 
UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to get descriptors for 
extensionBundleID (**)}., NSUnderlyingError=0x12da945a0 
{Error Domain=SBAvocadoDebuggingControllerErrorDomain Code=1 "Failed 
to get descriptors for extensionBundleID (**)" 
UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to get descriptors for 
extensionBundleID (**)}}}
```

[Screenshot of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7NHx.png)

I’m currently using Xcode 12.4 and test on an iPhone 8 which runs iOS 14.3.
Both the app and the widget extension are in the same app group and are signed with a valid development certificate, and the extension’s identifier uses the app’s identifier as the prefix.

Among the discussions I can find on the Internet, I’ve tried:

- Cleaning the build folder does not work (I’ve done this many times)
- Restarting the Xcode and iPhone does not work (I’ve also done this many times)
- Removing the widget extension and adding a fresh and untouched widget extension does not work (It seems that all the extensions stopped working)
- Ensuring the target platform version is lower than or equal to the testing platform does not work
- Creating a new project and copying only source files from the original project. Manually updating the project/target settings. This does not work.

Along with the widget extension, I also added an action extension to my project. But it appeared to be broken at the time I’ve found out the widget extension stopped working.

My guess: If the problem is related to the code in the extension, the extension should throw an error at runtime instead of failing to run the extension scheme. So I think the problem might be more related to the project/target settings. But I'm not quite sure about that.

I’ve spent the whole day searching for solutions. It seems that the discussions about the error message mentioned above are relatively rare.

I would appreciate any ideas. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I finally figured it out and solved this problem.

Letter case turns out to be the culprit.

One thing I haven't mentioned is that my project contains a folder reference name "Plugins" to be packed into the bundle. It contains several JavaScript files used by the app.

[Screenshot: How the file tree looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFqnT.png)

Then I noticed that in the "Build Phases" settings, the embedded app extensions are specified "PlugIns" as the default destination, which shares the same name with the "Plugins" folder listed in the "Copy Bundle Resources" if the letter case is ignored.

[Screenshot: "Build Phases" settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKDA3.png)

After exploring the build folder, I found that the widget extension was placed under the "Plugins" folder instead of the "PlugIns" one. When the widget extension is being launched, the "PlugIns" folder in the bundle is being looked up to find the `.appex` extension. The "PlugIns" folder does not exist but the "Plugins" one does in this scenario. And this can also explain why the app works but the extensions do not.

Renaming the folder to be included in the bundle solved my problem.